# Grid with multiple input fields per row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a "grid" with several input fields per row. Lets say each input field represents a day of the week.

**html:**

```
<table id="grid">
    <tr>
        <td><input class="fri" type="text" value="foo" /></td>
        <td><input class="mon" type="text" value="bar" /></td>
        <td><input class="tue" type="text" value="baz" /></td>
        <td><input class="wed" type="text" value="x" /></td>
        <td><input class="thu" type="text" value="y" /></td>
    </tr>
    ...
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#grid').on('change', '.fri', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    //do something
});

$('#grid').on('change', '.mon', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    //do something
});

// And so on...
```

There can be any number of rows, all having the same fields.

I made a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikolajkap/n79rjxt1/13/) of what I am trying to do.

However, I feel I am repeating myself a little too much (with the jQuery) and I was wondering if there is a way to do the above more concisely (preferably using jQuery).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rather use element selector instead of using individual IDs and then binding them:

```
$('#grid').on('change', 'input:text', function () {
   var value = $(this).val();
   //do something
});
```

Also if you have other textboxes in same table which you don't want to target then use multiple class selector:

```
$('#grid').on('change', '.fri,.mon,.tue', function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  //do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `event.target` like this:

```
$('#grid').on('change', function (e) {
    alert(e.target.value);
});
```

This would be the only jQuery you need.